# How can I fix Android app launch stopped error?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed my android app in my device. But getting **"Unfortunately, app has stopped."**

How can I debug the installed app? Is it possible to debug the app directly installed in the device?

Since code is not available with me

Comment: you can see the log in the android studio even if you don't have the source code, just set the logcat filter to "No Filter"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 3):

You can't connect debugger to an application if it uses a release build type where all of the information necessary for debugging is stripped out 
(true for apps from play market).

If you don't want to use a debugger but just to see logs you may see log in android studio or just by running `adb logcat` in terminal.

Android Studio 3.0 also has a feature of [Profile and Debug Pre-built APKs](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#enable-debug) but only if they were built with [debugging enabled](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#enable-debug)